# android SQLiteDatabase.Update() is returning 2, why?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have  my database and I query it for all items.

The list of items are:

```
Type- Coffee: Name- Cafe Latte
Type- Coffee: Name- Flavoured Latte
Type- Coffee: Name- Mocha
Type- Coffee: Name- Americano
Type- Coffee: Name- Short Black
Type- Coffee: Name- Flat White
Type- Coffee: Name- Espresso
Type- Coffee: Name- Espresso Con Panna
Type- Coffee: Name- Espresso Machiato
Type- Coffee: Name- Espresso Affogato
Type- Coffee: Name- Pot Of Coffee
```

and when i call this function:

```
public int EditItem(MenuItem menuItem){
      ContentValues itemNewValues = new ContentValues();
      //itemNewValues.put(ITEM_TYPE,menuItem.getType());
      itemNewValues.put(ITEM_NAME,menuItem.getName());
      itemNewValues.put(ITEM_REGPRICE,menuItem.getRegPrice());
      itemNewValues.put(ITEM_LARGEPRICE,menuItem.getLargePrice());
      String[] args = new String[1];
      args[0]= menuItem.getName();
      return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, itemNewValues,ITEM_NAME+"=?", args);
}

Log.i("TAG","updating (no of entries edited: " +localDBHandler.EditItem(new MenuItem("Coffee", "Flavoured Latte", "9.90","2.45")));
```

it returns "no of entries edited: 2"

but when I print out the table again it is exactly the same.

oh heres my create table statment:

```
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + 
    DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
    ITEM_TYPE + " text not null, " +
    ITEM_NAME + " text not null, " +
    ITEM_REGPRICE + " text not null, " +
    ITEM_LARGEPRICE + " text not null);";
```

Its bothering me as I don't want unwanted changes showing up further down the line that i'm just not seeing just now.

Comment: Include your schema. For debugging purposes, you might want to query the db on the same whereClause.

Comment: Yeah i got the schema, and took your advice to query the db on the same whereClause and it turned out that it was hitting it under two different categories, the second I hadn't implemented yet so It was never being visualized in my app, if you make it into an answer it mark it as my accepted answer :)

Comment: I extended this a bit to make it more universally applicable. You might still want to include your schema (`CREATE TABLE` statements) in your question to help folks follow along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your schema. If `db.update()` is returning `2`, then it updated two rows in your table, and so your `whereClause` matches two rows. For debugging purposes, query the table with the same `whereClause` and see what it returns. You may have to revise the schema and/or add a search criterion to narrow down the result set.